# What is the best way to store a local copy of a question with its answer?

Tags: support

I'd like to keep local copy of a question with its answer. Is there any tool that gives the best results? It seems that direct save-as command of FireFox does not give good results in terms of preserving the look and formatting of the web page.

Comment: this is the kind of thing that cries out for a good greasemonkey script.

Comment: I would use wget.

Answer (score 1):

Print to PDF...

Comment: Are you assuming that Adobe Acrobat is installed? Are you using some other tool to print to PDF? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @Turkistany: If you're on Windows, there are many free softwares that will allow you to print to PDF. PrimoPDF is one of them that works well for me.

Comment: Thanks Robin for your help